# Render conditional templates with Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I've a layout template with a left sidebar where I show information of Location passed entities  as an array.

Also in this template, I show a object Map with all of this locations.

I want to do click on a Location of my sidebar and then on the same template show another object Map replacing the previous with information of this Location. Keeping the sidebar with the information and not doing new queries on the database.

How to achieve this?

Ajax? Conditional layout?

I read this article but I don't understand how to solved my problem: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#overriding-a-template-that-also-extends-itself

PD: I'm using Twig template and Symfony2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a separate template for printing object map and, as you guessed, this would have to be done using `AJAX`. You would pass the data you want to show on map (not id as you don't want to query database again) and the controller would return formatted HTML.

However, this seems to me a bit overkill. I would always consider doing `JS` (with optional framework) in order to swap the content of sidebar with `Map` object.

**It really depends on which map API do you use**. If it could be controlled via `JS` I would look no further. It it could not, well then, `AJAX` is your natural choice....

### UPDATE:

OK, what you should do is create initial Map object that will be modified later on:

```
var theMap = null;

function initializeMap(){
    var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(some_latitude, some_longitude),
        zoom: 8, // goes from 0 to 18
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    theMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
    // you must have some element with ID = 'map_canvas'
}
```

`some_latitude` and `some_longitude` are fairly unimportant as you will most likely set new coordinates in a few moments.

Now assuming (but not crucial at all) that you use some of the `JS` frameworks (I prefer `jQuery`) you could bind click event to those location links:

```
var onlyMarker = null;
$('.location').click(function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    var newLatLang = new google.maps.LatLng($t.attr('data-lat') ,$t.attr('data-lng'));

    if ( onlyMarker  == null ) {
        onlyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: newLatLang
            map: theMap,
            title:  $t.attr('title')
        });
     }else{
        onlyMarker.setPosition(newLatLang);
     }
});
```

Now, relying on HTML5's 'data-*' attibutes is not good idea in particular as if you use any other version lower you will most likely end-up with invalid markup. The workaround is to for link (`<a>`) to carry id/key to `LatLng` object, for example:

```
// initially generated from `AJAX` or in `Twig` loop
var allLatlangs = [ 
    new google.maps.LatLngf(some_latitude, some_longitude),
    new google.maps.LatLngf(some_latitude, some_longitude),
    new google.maps.LatLngf(some_latitude, some_longitude),
];

$('.location').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
     var newLatLang = allLatLang(id);
     //....
     // everything else is the same 
     // ....
});
```

Don't forget to include Maps API with proper API key:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_HERE&sensor=true
```

In order to obtain valid API key follow this link: [API KEY HOW-TO](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=sr#api_key)

This link basically covers key steps that I have described here so study it and it should all come together nicely.

Also, if you're unsure how to retrieve some things from Maps you should consult reference:
[REFERENCE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) which has every method call described pretty good

Remember not to execute any of this code until everything is being loaded.

Hope this helped a bit :)

Comment: I'm using Google Maps API in PHP. I'll try with AJAX but I'm not sure how to do it because I don't know AJAX.

Comment: Ah what a coincidence! I started experimenting with Maps API just last night. Unfortunately, I'm probably won't be able to help you at least in few following days until I get a bit familiar with it but I hope someone else will ;)

Comment: OK, I did some digging last night though the Maps API and I think I'll be able to help you. Just need to return from work (around 6PM GMT+1) and if noone else writes the answer I will ;)

Comment: Not a problem at all. I have updated my answer which covers some basic example ;)